# Prove $\int_{\Omega} |u|^2 dx \le c\int_{\Omega} e^{|u|^2} dx$ through Hölder inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, holder-inequality

Last week I attended the last class of calculus of the semester and I got many problems left as an exercise. I have solved all of them but one.
It reads as follows.

Let $n\ge 2$ and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty bounded set. Prove that there exists a proper constant $c>0$ such that for all $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ it is
$$\int_{\Omega} |u|^2 dx \le c\int_{\Omega} e^{|u|^2} dx.$$
Was left as an hint to use Hölder inequality.

I am very confused about this exercise and I would ask for you help. My attempt so far is to write
$$\int_{\Omega} |u|^2 dx = \int_{\Omega} e^{\log(|u|^2)} dx,$$
but I do not understand how to use Hölder inequality to get the desired result.

Anyone could help?

Comment: the quantifiers are misplaced....You mean: prove the existence of $c$ such that for all $u$ and so on.

Comment: Hint: Using $$ e^x=1+x+\frac12x^2+\cdots\ge x$$ for $x\ge 0$, you will have $$ u^2\le e^{u^2}.$$ Then the inequality follows easily.

Comment: Not sure why you were told to use Hölder. $e^{z^2}>z^2$ $\forall z\in \mathbb R$ which is already enough.

Answer (score -1):

This is a sketch:

We can use Mclauren's identity for exponential map: $f(x) = f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{1!}\,x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}\,x^2+\cdots$. In that case, the map $e^y$ is equal to $1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}+...$.

Therefore, $\int\limits_\Omega e^{\lvert{u}\rvert^2} \, du = \int\limits_\Omega (1+\lvert{u}\rvert^2+\lvert{u}\rvert^4+\cdots)\,du = \int\limits_\Omega \lvert{u}\rvert^2 \, du+ \int\limits_\Omega(1+\frac{\lvert{u}\rvert^4}{(2!)^2}+\cdots)\,du$. If we prove, the right-hand side is greater than 0, we prove the desired equality.

Does it make sense?

Comment: That's not the Maclaurin series for $\exp$. You forgot the factorials: the formula is $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x - x_0)^n$. The series you wrote for $e^y$ would actually correspond to $\frac{1}{1 - y}$ when $|y| < 1$.

Comment: Also, the term $o(|u|^n)$ which is not clear (at least to me) how it should be integrated.

Comment: actually this is very fixable. The power series for $e^t$ tells us that for all $t\geq 0$, we have $e^t=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}\geq t$ (the equality is for all $t\in\Bbb{C}$ while the inequality holds for all $t\geq 0$). In particular, for all $x\in\Omega$, we have $e^{|u(x)|^2}\geq |u(x)|^2$, so the integral inequality in question holds with $c=1$. No need for Holder here.

Comment: @peek-a-boo this is intended on my answer. Which further change do you recommend?

Comment: Well technically you forgot the factorials in the mclaurin expansion

Comment: I fixed it. Anything else?

Comment: looks fine, but since you asked, I’ll nitpick :) In your chain of equalities with the integrals, the second equal sign, while definitely true, requires some justification, for example monotone convergence theorem. Now, this is a pretty heavy-hitting theorem, so it might just be better to use the inequality $e^{|u|^2}\geq |u|^2$ directly and integrate both sides. Anyway, this isn’t something you need to modify (and besides they mentioned the Lebesgue spaces $L^2(\Omega)$ so MCT should be accessible), just my 2 cents on presentation, whatever that’s worth.

Comment: "Drop the microphone". I mean, the pen